# Facebook API with PHP - To get name of property

Tags: php, facebook, api

I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.krizna.com/general/login-with-facebook-using-php/) to work on my fb API with PHP.
I am able to draw other properties like "locale", "gender".... However I have tried different method to draw "names" of "location" with different methods but failed. Would anyone recommend a correct syntax please?

Cheers!

```
<?php 
session_start();
    // added in v4.0.0
    require_once 'autoload.php';
    require 'functions.php';
    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
    // init app with app id and secret
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'appID','appSecretID' );
    // login helper with redirect_uri
        $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('domainURL' );
    try {
      $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
      // When Facebook returns an error
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
    }
    // see if we have a session
    if ( isset( $session ) ) {
      // graph api request for user data
      $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
      $response = $request->execute();
      // get response
      $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
            $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
            $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); 
            $fblastname = $graphObject->getProperty('last_name');
            $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');   
            $fBday = $graphObject->getProperty('birthday');
            $fbio = $graphObject->getProperty('bio');  
            $fgender = $graphObject->getProperty('gender'); 
            $fLocale = $graphObject->getProperty('locale');

/* These are the methods I tried to get the "name" of "hometown" but failed */

                $fHomeTown = $graphObject->getProperty('hometown')->'name';
                $fHomeTown = $graphObject->getProperty('hometown')->getProperty('name');
                $fHomeTwn = $fHomeTown->getProperty('name');
                $fRelationship = $graphObject->getProperty('relationship_status');
                $fQuotes = $graphObject->getProperty('quotes');
            /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
                $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
                $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
                $_SESSION['LASTNAME'] = $fblastname;
                $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
                $_SESSION['BDAY'] = $fBday;
                $_SESSION['BIO'] = $fbio;
                $_SESSION['GENDER'] = $fgender;
                $_SESSION['LANGUAGE'] = $fLocale;
                $_SESSION['HOMETOWN'] = $fHomeTown;
                $_SESSION['RELATIONSHIP'] = $fRelationship;  
                $_SESSION['QUOTES'] = $fQuotes;  

                checkuser($fbid,$fbfullname,$femail); // To update local DB
            /* ---- header location after session ----*/
          header("Location: index.php");
        } else {
          $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email'));
         header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You are not asking for the hometown field

Comment: Thanks! I have changed it to:   $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email, public_profile,user_friends'));

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
```

To:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,email,link,picture,locale');
```